# Differentiating between products for in-app iTunes

Tags: iphone, ipad, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, storekit

If I purchase a product, I call it using the product identifier(name) and then save the required details in NSUserDefaults. This way, I can unlock features whenever required after purchase. But if I use a different device, or delete the app, the NSUserDefaults gets reset, and the only info I get when restoring the product is the transaction id, date, receipt, etc. (no product identifier).

One way to solve this could be to save the transaction id on a server whenever I purchase a product, but I do not have access to a server, and want to be able to do this through the code.

so can anyone tell me :
is there any way I can access the product identifier when I restore the product? or is there any other solution that I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the product id as follows,

```
- (void)restoreTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction
{
    [self recordTransaction:transaction.originalTransaction];
    [self provideContent:transaction.originalTransaction.payment.productIdentifier];
    [self finishTransaction:transaction wasSuccessful:YES];
}
```

This [link](http://troybrant.net/blog/2010/01/in-app-purchases-a-full-walkthrough/) will be useful for you.

Comment: Just figured that out a while ago..for some reason I could not find that attribute. Thanks for the quick reply.
That link looks extremely useful...Thanks a ton!!